# Remove Leading Dots in Part of Table of Contents

Tags: fonts, spacing, table-of-contents, formatting

I am currently struggling with a few table of contents issues on LaTeX. I am trying to remove the leading dots on just one part of the table of contents, creating a consistent double-spacing throughout, and consistent space between chapter number and chapter title. I will say that I am using a style file from UNT that I have slightly edited, but below I have included some of the code that produces the table of contents:

```
\documentclass[12pt, titlepage, openany]{amsbook}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{TABLE OF CONTENTS}%\dotfill}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{chapter}{CHAPTER}{}{}}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\tocchapter[3]{%
  \indentlabel{\@ifnotempty{#2}{\ignorespaces#2.\quad}}#3\dotfill%
}
\makeatother
\begin{doublespace}
\tableofcontents
\end{doublespace}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
```

That I know of, I am not using the tocloft package since I seem to always get errors when I try to compile and everything seems to be working fine without it despite this one issue. There are also two modifications that I have used which were found online:

1).

```
\makeatletter
\def\@tocline#1#2#3#4#5#6#7{\relax
\ifnum #1>\c@tocdepth % then omit
\else
\par \addpenalty\@secpenalty\addvspace{#2}%
\begingroup \hyphenpenalty\@M
\@ifempty{#4}{%
  \@tempdima\csname r@tocindent\number#1\endcsname\relax
}{%
  \@tempdima#4\relax
}%
\parindent\z@ \leftskip#3\relax \advance\leftskip\@tempdima\relax
\rightskip\@pnumwidth plus4em \parfillskip-\@pnumwidth
#5\leavevmode\hskip-\@tempdima #6\nobreak\relax
\ifnum#1<0\hfill\else\dotfill\fi\hbox to\@pnumwidth{\@tocpagenum{#7}}\par
\nobreak
\endgroup
\fi}
\makeatother
```

2).

```
\makeatletter
\def\@dottedtocline#1#2#3#4#5{%
\ifnum #1>\c@tocdepth \else
\vskip \z@ \@plus.2\p@
{\ifnum #1>\c@sectocnonumdepth \def\numberline##1{\hb@xt@\@tempdima{\hfil}}\fi%
 \leftskip #2\relax \rightskip \@tocrmarg \parfillskip -\rightskip
 \parindent #2\relax\@afterindenttrue
 \interlinepenalty\@M
 \leavevmode
 \@tempdima #3\relax
 \advance\leftskip \@tempdima \null\nobreak\hskip -\leftskip
 {#4}\nobreak
 \leaders\hbox{$\m@th
    \mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern \@dotsep
    mu$}\hfill
 \nobreak
 \hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hfil\normalfont \normalcolor #5}%
 \par}%
\fi}
\makeatother


\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{TABLE OF CONTENTS}%\dotfill}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{chapter}{CHAPTER}{}{}}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\tocchapter[3]{%
\indentlabel{\@ifnotempty{#2}{\ignorespaces#2.\enskip }}#3\dotfill%
}
\makeatother
\begin{doublespace}
\tableofcontents
\end{doublespace}

\end{document}
```

And lastly, here is a screenshot of how it looks

[image]

Just to be clear, I need to remove the leading dots from the word CHAPTER following the words TABLE OF CONTENTS, and create a consistent spacing. Any assistance on this is greatly appreciated. A million thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

So I was able to fix the spacing issue a lot better compared to how it is seen in the picture. I used the \enskip command instead of the \quad that was originally there. However I am still stuck on removing the leading dots from the word CHAPTER following the words TABLE OF CONTENTS. As always, any help is always welcomed and greatly appreciated.

Comment: The setting of a ToC entry is either specific to the `\documentclass`, or a package. You haven't disclosed any of this. Could you provide the community with something that would help replicate your current results? Something in the form of a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)? Otherwise there may be many options that answerers waste their time on...

Comment: Yes, I just included that following the first paragraph, thanks.

Comment: Please follow the link Werner provided and read about how to construct an MWE. If you provide a real MWE, you will be surprised how quickly someone answers the question to your satisfaction.

Comment: try replace `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{chapter}{CHAPTER}{}{}}` with `\addtocontents{toc}{CHAPTER}`

Comment: It did remove the dots, but the word CHAPTER was pushed forward ,as if it were indented, as well as some spacing was added under it. I appreciate the suggestion though, I don't think I would have thought of that on my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've removed an extra `\dotfill` from `\tocchapter` since there is already a `\dotfill` as part of `\@tocline`. Secondly, I've created a macro that specifically handles your `CHAPTER` entry via a local redefinition within the ToC itself:

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsbook}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\tocchapter[3]{%
  \indentlabel{\@ifnotempty{#2}{\ignorespaces#2.\quad}}#3%
}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\def\@tocline#1#2#3#4#5#6#7{\relax
  \ifnum #1>\c@tocdepth % then omit
  \else
    \par \addpenalty\@secpenalty\addvspace{#2}%
    \begingroup \hyphenpenalty\@M
    \@ifempty{#4}{%
      \@tempdima\csname r@tocindent\number#1\endcsname\relax
    }{%
      \@tempdima#4\relax
    }%
    \parindent\z@ \leftskip#3\relax \advance\leftskip\@tempdima\relax
    \rightskip\@pnumwidth plus4em \parfillskip-\@pnumwidth
    #5\leavevmode\hskip-\@tempdima #6\nobreak\relax
    \ifnum#1<0\hfill\else\dotfill\fi\hbox to\@pnumwidth{\@tocpagenum{#7}}\par
    \nobreak
    \endgroup
  \fi}
\makeatother

% Create a way of treating CHAPTER
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\l@specialchapter}{%
  \let\@tocpagenum\@gobble
  \@tocline{-1}{8pt plus 1pt}{0pt}{}{}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\clearpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{TABLE OF CONTENTS}%\dotfill}
\tableofcontents

% Update the chapter ToC entries to use \l@specialchapter
\makeatletter
\addtocontents{toc}{\begingroup
  \let\protect\l@chapter\l@specialchapter}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{CHAPTER}
\addtocontents{toc}{\endgroup}
\makeatother

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @Werner!! This did the trick just as it was supposed to!! I am now told that the spacing after each chapter is one-and-a-half instead of double. I tried to include the table of contents within a doublespacing evironment, but I don't think that did the trick. Would you happen to know how to correct this? Again, a million and one thanks for these commands for the table of contents!!